# Are free monads also zippily applicative?

Tags: haskell, tree, monads, applicative, free-monad

I think I've come up with an interesting "zippy" `Applicative` instance for [`Free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free).

```
data FreeMonad f a = Free (f (FreeMonad f a))
                   | Return a

instance Functor f => Functor (FreeMonad f) where
    fmap f (Return x) = Return (f x)
    fmap f (Free xs) = Free (fmap (fmap f) xs)

instance Applicative f => Applicative (FreeMonad f) where
    pure = Return

    Return f <*> xs = fmap f xs
    fs <*> Return x = fmap ($x) fs
    Free fs <*> Free xs = Free $ liftA2 (<*>) fs xs
```

It's sort of a zip-longest strategy. For example, using `data Pair r = Pair r r` as the functor (so `FreeMonad Pair` is an externally labelled binary tree):

```
    +---+---+    +---+---+               +-----+-----+
    |       |    |       |      <*>      |           |
 +--+--+    h    x    +--+--+   -->   +--+--+     +--+--+
 |     |              |     |         |     |     |     |
 f     g              y     z        f x   g x   h y   h z
```

I haven't seen anyone mention this instance before. Does it break any `Applicative` laws? (It doesn't agree with the usual `Monad` instance of course, which is "substitutey" rather than "zippy".)

Comment: It's trivial to prove that the identity, homomorphism, and interchange laws all hold. The composition law is tougher. After splitting it into cases, it looks like the toughest part will be proving that `liftA2 (<*>) (Free $ liftA2 (<*>) (fmap (fmap (.)) fu) fv) fw = liftA2 (<*>) fu (liftA2 (<*>) fv fw)`, where `fu`, `fv`, and `fw` are all of type `Applicative f => f (FreeMonad f a)`.

Comment: @JosephSible I’ve been thinking about that some more. Since the RHS of the `Free`/`Free` case of `<*>` is identical to that of `Compose`’s, the `Free`/`Free`/`Free` case of the composition law follows directly from the correctness of `Compose`’s instance (and the induction hypothesis). If there’s a bug, it’ll be when one or more of the values is a `Return`, I think.

Comment: Though I didn't actually write down the proof, I believe the mixed-`Free`-and-`Return` cases of the composition law must hold due to parametricity. I also suspect that should be easier to show using [the monoidal presentation](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/).

Comment: @duplode Seems to me that parametricity says that there’s only one _type_-correct implementation of the `Return` cases (namely mapping over the other tree), but that doesn’t necessarily imply that it’s lawful. Unless there’s a free theorem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**, it looks like this is a lawful `Applicative`. Weird!

As [@JosephSible points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148561/are-free-monads-also-zippily-applicative#comment97041830_55148561), you can read off the **identity**, **homomorphism** and **interchange** laws immediately from the definitions. The only tricky one is the **composition** law.

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
```

There are eight cases to check, so strap in.

- One case with three `Return`s: `pure (.) <*> Return f <*> Return g <*> Return z`

  - Follows trivially from associativity of `(.)`.
- Three cases with one `Free`:

  - `pure (.) <*> Free u <*> Return g <*> Return z`

    - Working backwards from `Free u <*> (Return g <*> Return z)` you get `fmap (\f -> f (g z)) (Free u)`, so this follows from the functor law.
  - ```
    pure (.) <*> Return f <*> Free v <*> Return z
    fmap ($z) $ fmap f (Free v)
    fmap (\g -> f (g z)) (Free v)                  -- functor law
    fmap (f . ($z)) (Free v)
    fmap f (fmap ($z) (Free v))                    -- functor law
    Return f <$> (Free v <*> Return z)             -- RHS of `<*>` (first and second cases)
    QED
    ```
  - `pure (.) <*> Return f <*> Return g <*> Free w`

    - Reduces immediately to `fmap (f . g) (Free w)`, so follows from the functor law.
- Three cases with one `Return`:

  - ```
    pure (.) <*> Return f <*> Free v <*> Free w
    Free $ fmap (<*>) (fmap (fmap (f.)) v) <*> w
    Free $ fmap (\y z -> fmap (f.) y <*> z) v <*> w                  -- functor law
    Free $ fmap (\y z -> fmap (.) <*> Return f <*> y <*> z) v <*> w  -- definition of fmap, twice
    Free $ fmap (\y z -> Return f <*> (y <*> z)) v <*> w             -- composition
    Free $ fmap (\y z -> fmap f (y <*> z)) v <*> w                   -- RHS of fmap, definition of liftA2
    Free $ fmap (fmap f) $ fmap (<*>) v <*> w                        -- functor law, eta reduce
    fmap f $ Free $ liftA2 (<*>) v w                                 -- RHS of fmap
    Return f <*> Free v <*> Free w                                   -- RHS of <*>
    QED.
    ```
  - ```
    pure (.) <*> Free u <*> Return g <*> Free w
    Free ((fmap (fmap ($g))) (fmap (fmap (.)) u)) <*> Free w
    Free (fmap (fmap (\f -> f . g) u)) <*> Free w                    -- functor law, twice
    Free $ fmap (<*>) (fmap (fmap (\f -> f . g)) u) <*> w
    Free $ fmap (\x z -> fmap (\f -> f . g) x <*> z) u <*> w         -- functor law
    Free $ fmap (\x z -> pure (.) <*> x <*> Return g <*> z) u <*> w
    Free $ fmap (\x z -> x <*> (Return g <*> z)) u <*> w             -- composition
    Free $ fmap (<*>) u <*> fmap (Return g <*>) w                    -- https://gist.github.com/benjamin-hodgson/5b36259986055d32adea56d0a7fa688f
    Free u <*> fmap g w                                              -- RHS of <*> and fmap
    Free u <*> (Return g <*> w)
    QED.
    ```
  - ```
    pure (.) <*> Free u <*> Free v <*> Return z
    Free (fmap (<*>) (fmap (fmap (.)) u) <*> v) <*> Return z
    Free (fmap (\x y -> fmap (.) x <*> y) u <*> v) <*> Return z        -- functor law
    Free $ fmap (fmap ($z)) (fmap (\x y -> fmap (.) x <*> y) u <*> v)
    Free $ liftA2 (\x y -> (fmap ($z)) (fmap (.) x <*> y)) u v         -- see Lemma, with f = fmap ($z) and g x y = fmap (.) x <*> y
    Free $ liftA2 (\x y -> fmap (.) x <*> y <*> Return z) u v          -- interchange
    Free $ liftA2 (\x y -> x <*> (y <*> Return z)) u v                 -- composition
    Free $ liftA2 (\f g -> f <*> fmap ($z) g) u v                      -- interchange
    Free $ fmap (<*>) u <*> (fmap (fmap ($z)) v)                       -- https://gist.github.com/benjamin-hodgson/5b36259986055d32adea56d0a7fa688f
    Free u <*> Free (fmap (fmap ($z)) v)
    Free u <*> (Free v <*> Return z)
    QED.
    ```
- Three `Free`s: `pure (.) <*> Free u <*> Free v <*> Free w`

  - This case only exercises the `Free`/`Free` case of `<*>`, whose right-hand side is identical to that of [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html)'s `<*>`. So this one follows from the correctness of `Compose`'s instance.

For the `pure (.) <*> Free u <*> Free v <*> Return z` case I used a lemma:

**Lemma**: `fmap f (fmap g u <*> v) = liftA2 (\x y -> f (g x y)) u v`.

```
fmap f (fmap g u <*> v)
pure (.) <*> pure f <*> fmap g u <*> v  -- composition
fmap (f .) (fmap g u) <*> v             -- homomorphism
fmap ((f .) . g) u <*> v                -- functor law
liftA2 (\x y -> f (g x y)) u v          -- eta expand
QED.
```

Variously I'm using functor and applicative laws under the induction hypothesis.

This was pretty fun to prove! I'd love to see a formal proof in Coq or Agda (though I suspect the termination/positivity checker might mess it up).

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, I will use this answer to expand on [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148561/are-free-monads-also-zippily-applicative/55152385#comment97046974_55148561):

> Though I didn't actually write down the proof, I believe the mixed-Free-and-Return cases of the composition law must hold due to parametricity. I also suspect that should be easier to show using [the monoidal presentation](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/).

The monoidal presentation of the `Applicative` instance here is:

```
unit = Return ()

Return x *&* v = (x,) <$> v
u *&* Return y = (,y) <$> u
-- I will also piggyback on the `Compose` applicative, as suggested above.
Free u *&* Free v = Free (getCompose (Compose u *&* Compose v))
```

Under the monoidal presentation, the composition/associativity law is:

```
(u *&* v) *&* w ~ u *&* (v *&* w)
```

Now let's consider one of its mixed cases; say, the `Free`-`Return`-`Free` one:

```
(Free fu *&* Return y) *&* Free fw ~ Free fu *&* (Return y *&* Free fw)

(Free fu *&* Return y) *&* Free fw -- LHS
((,y) <$> Free fu) *&* Free fw

Free fu *&* (Return y *&* Free fw) -- RHS
Free fu *&* ((y,) <$> Free fw)
```

Let's have a closer look at this left-hand side. `(,y) <$> Free fu` applies `(,y) :: a -> (a, b)` to the `a` values found in `Free fu :: FreeMonad f a`. Parametricity (or, more specifically, the free theorem for `(*&*)`) means that it doesn't matter if we do that before or after using `(*&*)`. That means the left-hand side amounts to:

```
first (,y) <$> (Free fu *&* Free fw)
```

Analogously, the right-hand side becomes:

```
second (y,) <$> (Free fu *&* Free fw)
```

Since `first (,y) :: (a, c) -> ((a, b), c)` and `second (y,) :: (a, c) -> (a, (b, c))` are the same up to reassociation of pairs, we have:

```
first (,y) <$> (Free fu *&* Free fw) ~ second (y,) <$> (Free fu *&* Free fw)
-- LHS ~ RHS
```

The other mixed cases can be dealt with analogously. For the rest of the proof, see [Benjamin Hodgson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55152385/2751851).

Answer (score 3):

From the [definition of `Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative):

> If `f` is also a `Monad`, it should satisfy
>
> - `pure` = `return`
> - `(<*>)` = `ap`
> - `(*>)` = `(>>)`

So this implementation would break the applicative laws that say it *must* agree with the `Monad` instance.

That said, there's no reason you couldn't have a newtype wrapper for `FreeMonad` that didn't have a monad instance, but did have the above applicative instance

```hs
newtype Zip f a = Zip { runZip :: FreeMonad f a }
  deriving Functor

instance Applicative f => Applicative (Zip f) where -- ...
```

Comment: Sure, let's forget about `Monad` for now. Is the `Applicative` instance itself lawful?

Comment: Sure, it looks like it should satisfy the [identity, interchange, homomorphism and composition laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) to me, but it'd probably be a good check to write the proofs out using equational reasoning